# SQL Server float comparison in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, floating-point

Unfortunately, I have two tables to compare float datatypes between. I've read up on trying casts, converts, using a small difference and tried them all.

The strange part is, this only fails when I'm executing a stored procedure. If I cut-and-paste the body of the stored procedure into a SSMS window, it works just great.

Sample SQL:

```
set @newEnvRiskLevel = -1

select
    @newEnvRiskLevel = rl.RiskLevelId
from
    LookupTypes lt
inner join 
    RiskLevels rl on lt.LookupTypeId = rl.RiskLevelTypeFk
where
    lt.Code = 'RISK_LEVEL_ENVIRONMENTAL'
    and convert(numeric(1, 0), rl.RiskFactor) = @newEnvScore

set @errorCode = @@ERROR

if (@newEnvRiskLevel = -1 or @errorCode != 0)
begin
    print 'newEnvScore = ' + cast(@newEnvScore as varchar) + ' and risk level = ' + cast(isnull(@newEnvRiskLevel, -1) as varchar)
    print 'ERROR finding environmental risk level for code ' + @itemCode + ', skipping record'
    set @recordsErrored = @recordsErrored + 1
    goto NEXTREC
end
```

My `@newEnvScore` variable is also a `float` converted to `numeric(1, 0)`. I've verified that there are only 0, 1, 2, and 3 for values in the RiskFactor column, and (via debug) that `@newEnvScore` has a value of 2.  I've also verified that my query has a row with code = 'RISK_LEVEL_ENVIRONMENTAL' and RiskFactor = 2.

I've verified via debug that failure is due to @newEnvRiskLevel staying at -1 and that @errorCode is 0.

I've also tried cast to both decimal and int, convert to int, and "rl.RiskFactor - @newEnvScore < 1" in my where clause, none of which set newEnvRiskLevel.

As I say, it's *only* when running this as a stored procedure that failure happens, which is the part I really don't understand. I'd expect SQL Server to be deterministic, whether the SQL is running the body of a stored procedure, or running the exact same SQL in a SSMS tab.

Comment: So what isn't working? Do you get an error? Does it not return the correct information?

Comment: Supplying the contexts of the table would help as well. Yeah I know you told us what the values were, but nowt beats some tangible data to paste n run.

Comment: Also I've found issues when doing casts such as convert(numeric(1, 0), rl.RiskFactor) = @newEnvScore. Have you tried convert(numeric(1, 0), rl.RiskFactor) = Convert(numeric(1, 0), @newEnvScore) ? Redundant perhaps when strange things can happen when casting...

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  As I said, @newEnvRiskLevel stays at -1 after the select, but _only_ when running this as a procedure; if I cut & paste the body of a procedure out to an SSMS window, the select finds a match.  Same database.

Comment: This is a one-off, mass update so I'm not super worried about using a sproc to run vs inline SQL.  Now it's just curiousity; why would the exact same select run differently just because it's executed in a stored procedure?  Anyway, thanks for the ideas, I may get back to this and try some more.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that you do post neither your stored procedure nor a complete script. It is difficult to diagnose a problem without a useful demonstration. But I see the use of "goto" which is concerning in many ways. I also see the use of a select statement to assign a local variable - which is often a problem because the developer might be assuming an assignment always occurs. To demonstrate - with a bonus at the end

```
set nocount on;
declare @risk smallint; 
declare @risklevels table (risklevel float primary key, code varchar(10)); 
insert @risklevels(risklevel, code) values (1, 'test'), (2, 'test'), (-5, 'test'); 

-- here is your assignment logic. Notice that @risk is 
-- never changed because there are no matching rows. 
set @risk = 0; 
select @risk = risklevel from @risklevels where code = 'zork'; 
select @risk; 

-- here is a better IMO way to make the assignment. Note that
-- @risk is set to NULL when there are no matching rows. 
set @risk = -1; 
set @risk = (select risklevel from @risklevels where code = 'zork'); 
select @risk; 

-- and a last misconception. What value is @risk set to? and why? 
set @risk = -1; 
select @risk = risklevel from @risklevels where code = 'test'; 
select @risk;
```

Whether this is the source of your problem (or contributes to it) I can't say. But it is a possibility. And storing integers in a floating point datatype is just a problem generally. Even if you cannot change your table, you can change your local variables and force the use of a more appropriate datatype. So perhaps that is another change you should consider.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  The sproc is fairly large, I didn't want to overwhelm everyone.  As for using null, I had used that value instead of -1 initially, and then checked 'is null' in my if statement.  No matter, either null or -1 is a dummy value which tells me I didn't match.  As I said above, this is a one-off, mass update, so no harm in running in manually; now I'm just curious as to why executing SQL in a tab in SSMS would act differently than the exact SQL wrapped in a CREATE PROCEDURE statement, then executing that procedure.